# Is there a card that protects me from a (self-)milling death?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there a card with the ability: *You do not lose the game being for unable to draw a card*?

I've found one so far; [Mine, Mine, Mine!](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9787) but it applies to all players.

A little back story; I have [Reliquary Tower](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reliquary%20Tower) that has the ability; *You have no maximum hand size*. I also have several cards that allow me to get an abundance of card draws: for instance I have [Dragon Appeasement](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/details.aspx?name=dragon%20appeasement), if these two are paired in my devour deck I can get a wealth of cards, enabling me to play out [Thromok the Insatiable](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=265155) all the sooner.

This would of course mill me out pretty quickly, so I was hoping for a card that does for me in prevention of loss by having no library what [Phyrexian Unlife](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218058) does for having 0 life.

I'm hoping there's a keyword I didn't think of, and that someone has a card in mind for this.

Comment: There are cards which cause you to skip your draw step, such as your Dragon Appeasement. You could also use something like Feldon's cane or Paradigm Shift to reshuffle your graveyard into your library.

Comment: Those are both good, thank you @Nick. They're kind of one shots though; I'm assuming that Paradigm Shift would end up being the only card in  my graveyard as it would be on the stack busy resolving whilst the action is being carried out? Not the end of the world if I've got a few of them though :)

Comment: And since you're skipping your draw step anyway with Dragon Appeasement, why not use Ivory Gargoyle to gain a free creature to sacrifice each turn?

Comment: You could also use Elixir of Immortality which gets shuffled back into your deck each time you use it.

Comment: Nice, very nice :D

Comment: There are several cards that let you replace a card draw, like 'Abundance', 'Pursuit of Knowledge', 'Tomorrow, Azami's Familiar', 'Sages of the Anima', 'Obstinate Familiar' and 'Parallel Thoughts'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Win the game

Cards which change "draw from an empty library" into a win condition:

- [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLaboratory%20Maniac%5d) is the most famous card to do this.
- [Jace, Wielder of Mysteries](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Wielder%20of%20Mysteries%5d) has a static effect to do the same.
- [Thassa's Oracle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThassa%27s%5d%2b%5bOracle%5d) has an enters the battlefield trigger which causes you to win if the number of cards in your library is less than your devotion to blue.

### Shuffle your graveyard into your library

Some cards can cause you to shuffle your graveyard into your library, including [Emrakul, the Aeons torn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmrakul%2c%20the%20Aeons%20torn%5d) (among other mythic eldrazi cards). [Elixir of Immortality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElixir%20of%20Immortality%5d) will do the same, cheaper for a gain of 5 life. Other similar cards exist, including [Finale of Revelation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFinale%20of%20Revelation%5d).  [Gaea's Blessing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGaea%27s%5d%2b%5bBlessing%5d) is notable for shuffling your graveyard into your library specifically if it itself is milled.

### Don't draw a card

[Blue Sun's Zenith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlue%5d%2b%5bSun%27s%5d%2b%5bZenith%5d) You can read this as "UUU: don't draw a card", and add the card to your library, so you can draw it next turn and repeat.

### Don't lose the game

Various cards include a "you can't lose the game" effect, such as [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlatinum%20Angel%5d) and [Angel Grace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%20Grace%5d).

### Miscellaneous

- There is also the slightly convoluted combo of [Consecrated Sphinx](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConsecrated%20Sphinx%5d), [Notion Thief](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNotion%20Thief%5d) which you then [Donate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDonate%5d) to your opponent before doing anything to cause you to draw a card outside of your draw step. The draw will be redirected to your opponent, which will trigger the sphinx, which will allow you to redirect 2 more draws and repeat the process to mill your opponent out to defeat. Probably not as good as Lab maniac, but worth remembering.
- [Nexus of Fate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNexus%20of%20Fate%5d) has a replacement effect which causes it to go to your library rather than your graveyard, so you never deck yourself if you can cast it every turn (unless something else causes you to draw). As Nexus of Fate gives you an extra turn, this is a win con if you have some way of damaging the opponent on every turn.
- [Murderous Rider](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMurderous%20Rider%5d) goes to the bottom of your library when it dies so you can play a similar trick with this if you can draw it and kill it every turn.

Comment: Oh now those are cool, I've seen Emrakul before and always thought it just plain mean! But Laboratory Maniac is awesome, a completely different twist to what I was trying to achieve. Thanks @Rawgramming

Comment: Love that combo, my wife will never forgive me if I use it on her :D

Comment: [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=206329) will also prevent you to lose the game, even if Laboratory Maniac seems way better in your case.

Comment: good point, i will add it (and one other) to the list

Comment: Platinum Angel is ridiculous, I love it!

Comment: Elixer of Immortality is pretty boss as well. And you gain life.

Comment: I've tried to make this into a canonical answer; please consider editing this answer rather than writing a new answer.

Comment: If we're talking about not drawing cards (and only applying to you) you can't forget Necropotence

Comment: @CLockeWork Platinum angel is generally considered to be a bad card actually, being an artifact creature almost every kind of removal will work on it, and generally the idea is the best way to not lose is to just win instead.

Comment: To add to your answer, you can use cards which prohibit you from drawing cards. For example [Underrealm Lich](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Underrealm+Lich)

Answer (score 4):

Note that you don't lose for having an empty library.  You lose for drawing from an empty library.

[Dragon Appeasement](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDragon%20Appeasement%5d) already probably does what you want.  It lets you skip your draw step, and its draw ability is optional, so you will only get milled if another player has a spell or ability that forces you draw a card (such as [Braingeyser](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBraingeyser%5d)) or you play a card that forces you to draw (don't do this).

For cards that protect you from being milled in general, there are:

- Cards with replacement effects for card draws.  The key phrase in the oracle text is "would draw a card".  This comes in several variations:

  - "if you would draw a card", such as [Abundance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAbundance%5d), [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLaboratory%20Maniac%5d), or [Obstinate Familiar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bObstinate%20Familiar%5d)
  - "the next time you would draw a card", such as [Words of Worship](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWords%20of%20Worship%5d)
  - "if a player would draw a card", such as [Uba Mask](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUba%20Mask%5d)
- Cards that let you shuffle your graveyard back into your library, such as [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmrakul%2c%20the%20Aeons%20Torn%5d) or [Elixir of Immortality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElixir%20of%20Immortality%5d)
- Cards that say "you can't lose the game", such as [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlatinum%20Angel%5d) or [Gideon of the Trials](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20of%20the%20Trials%5d)

Comment: The first two bullet points there are really describing two variants of the same thing: replacement effects that replace drawing cards with something else. The key phrase is "would draw a card", and the word "instead" later in the ability or effect.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That's a good point.  I've listed them differently only because they have slightly different implication for deck building (the Words cycle require mana to use, as opposed to always on effects like Obstinate Familiar)

Comment: You can say that about almost anything here. Abundance and Laboratory Maniac go in very different kinds of decks, and accomplish very different deckbuilding goals.

Answer (score 0):

[Jace, Wielder of Mysteries](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=jace%2C%20wielder%20of%20mysteries) is a planeswalker from "War of the Spark" which can protect you from self-mill death, by making it a game winning condition.

[image]

Comment: It's a turn 9 win, though, without mana acceleration/counter manipulation.